# IBM Watson integration with WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp, ibm-watson

Is it possible to to integrate IBM Watson Assistant (Conversation) with WhatsApp? I have tried searching on the internet but haven't found much.

Comment: Anything is possible. The real questions are whether or not it is *easy*, and whether doing so will accomplish your goals.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I know it is possible with Facebook but haven't found anything on whatsapp. Some articles suggest that it could be possible but do not list any details on how. Do you have any idea or know if any documentation that I could go through to get an idea?

Answer (score 0):

We're working on integration to Watson IBM which would bring all channels supported by [amio.io](http://amio.io) to it. WhatsApp is obviously one of them we're aiming to provide. :-)

Comment: And have you been able to acheive integration with Whatsapp because what i have read suggests that Whatsapp does not allows chatbot and may also disable the number if a chatbot is found. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: We have no evidence that bots are forbidden however we're not aware of WhatsApp API policies. They focus on notification services but we've seen several implementation with automatic responses, i.e. help desk auto responses. If you call it chatbot or not is on you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible with services such as [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io)
First connect [IBM Watson with Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/ibm-watson-chatbot/).
[image: IBM Watson integration step in Kommunicate]

Then, connect Whatsapp from Integration section.

Disclaimer: I am Cofounder of Kommunicate